# Strange Error in C++ Program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So I have written a simple calculator for study purpose. But I can't get it working because I get a strange error. I tried everything I could but I couldn't fix the error. Please have a look at it and tell me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double add (double x, double y)
{
double addition = x+y;
return addition;
}
double sub (double x ,double y)
{
double subtraction = x-y;
return subtraction;
}
double mul (double x , double y)
{
double multiplication = x*y;
return multiplication;
}
double div (double x, double y)
{
double division = x/y;
return division;
}
int main ()
{
int x; int y; int op;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> x;
cout << "Enter second number: ";
cin >> y;
cout << "1: Addition,   2: Subtraction, 3: Multiplication,  4: Division" <<   endl;
cout << "What operation you want: ";
cin >> op;
switch (op)
{
case 1:
cout << x << " + " << y << " = " <<  add(x, y);`enter code here`
break;

case 2:
cout << x << " - " << y << " = " << sub(x,y);
break;

case 3:
cout << x << " * " << y << " = " << mul (x,y);
break;
case 4:
cout << x << " / " << y << " = " << div (x,y);
break;
default:
cout << "Invalid operation"
}

}
```

Comment: What strange error? My mind reading abilities are not that good.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46e15a9f289d4d5c

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ pointed out with the online c++ compiler you have ***\`enter code here\`*** at the end of one of your lines of code. Fix that first.

Comment: @drescherjm It's pointing out other errors now, I fixed the `enter code here`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you used

```
using namespace std;
```

You're running into conflict with the standard function [`div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div). Specifically, as there exists overload `std::div_t div( int x, int y );` and you're calling div with two integers, this will get called.

In general avoid using `using namespace std;` in your code.

In this case, the easiest fix is to just name the function differently:

```
double divide(double x, double y)
{
    double division = x/y;
    return division;
}
```

Since there is no stdlib overload taking two doubles, you could also do something like this, to make the compiler use your function:

```
div(static_cast<double>(x),static_cast<double>(y));
```

Another approach would be placing your functions into a namespace:

```
namespace ops {
double div(double x, double y) {
    double division = x/y;
    return division;
}
} // namespace ops

...

cout << x << " / " << y << " = " << ops::div(x,y);
```

Comment: I would suggest removing `using namespace std;` to avoid the problem and future similar issues even though it will require 5 extra characters to type when using something from the standard library.

Comment: @drescherjm Absolutely true, however even without it, at least on coliru, `std::div` seems to be injected into global namespace and still gets picked.